# How can I explicitly maintain view state for dynamically created user controls?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate, asp.net-4.0

I have a search form that offers a number of different search options, such as 'search on natural name', 'search on legal name', 'search on address' etc. These are defined by static 'factory' methods on a `PropertySearchOption` class. Each search option specifies a user control containing the search fields required for that optiom, e.g. the natural name option has name and surname fields. The search option used is determined by a *RadioButtonList* on the main search page, and when the selection changes in this list I dynamically load the required user control.  My problem is that I can't find a way to preserve the view state of the dynamical control and its search fields. Here is the core code I am using:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="searchTypeOptions" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SearchTypeOptionsSelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="NaturalName">Name (Natural)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="LegalName">Legal Name (Business)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ErfDetails">Erf Details</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="PhysicalAddress">Physical Address</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="FarmDetails">Farm</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var typeOption = searchTypeOptions.SelectedItem;
        if (typeOption == null)
        {
            searchTypeOptions.SelectedValue = "ErfDetails";
            LoadSearchForm();
        }
    }
}

protected void SearchTypeOptionsSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadSearchForm();
}

protected virtual void LoadSearchForm()
{
    SearchOption = (PropertySearchOption)typeof(PropertySearchOption).GetProperty(searchTypeOptions.SelectedValue, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null);
    searchFormPlaceHolder.Controls.Clear();
    var searchForm = LoadControl(SearchOption.FormControlUrl);
    searchFormPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(searchForm);
    searchTypeLabel.Text = SearchOption.Description;
}
```

I have to set *EnableViewState* to false on `searchFormPlaceHolder`, or I get a viewstate exception when I try and change the current option, and like this the dynamic selection of search forms works fine. However, on the button click postback to perform the search, I lose the search form, because it is only created in Page_Init on the first load, not postbacks. If I place `LoadSearchForm` outside the if block, it fails because on postback, the `SelectedValue` of the radio button list is empty.

What can I do, or what should I do, to in a scenario like this, besides run away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the search type option in a HiddenField, so you can create the search form at each postback (and remember to set a unique id to your dynamically created controls)

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var typeOption = searchTypeOptions.SelectedItem;
        if (typeOption == null)
        {
            searchTypeOptions.SelectedValue =
                 myHiddenField.Value = "ErfDetails";
            LoadSearchForm("ErfDetails");
        }
    }
    else
       LoadSearchForm(Request.Form[myHiddenField.UniqueID]);
}

override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
    myHiddenField.Value = searchTypeOptions.SelectedValue;
}

protected void SearchTypeOptionsSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadSearchForm(searchTypeOptions.SelectedValue);
}

protected virtual void LoadSearchForm(string option)
{
    SearchOption = (PropertySearchOption)typeof(PropertySearchOption).GetProperty(option, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null);
    searchFormPlaceHolder.Controls.Clear();
    var searchForm = LoadControl(SearchOption.FormControlUrl);

    searchForm.ID = "mySearchForm";

    searchFormPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(searchForm);
    searchTypeLabel.Text = SearchOption.Description;
}
```